Proper detrend and anomaly method for monthly data?
I'm trying to calculate JJA anomalies of SST(Sea Surface Temperature) data.
before calculating the anomalies, i tried to detrend the data.
However, I am confused whether I should detrend June, July, and August separately to get the JJA anomaly or detrend against the JJA mean.
I know that when I get the JJA anomaly, I get the anomaly for each month and average it, but I was wondering if this also applies to detrend.

What is "JJA"? (Acronyms are tricky).

sorry it means june-july-august, the summer season
